# Simplify Product of sines

Tags: trigonometry, products, trigonometric-series

Is there a way simplify this product?

$$
\sin\left({n} \frac{\pi}{2}\right)  \sin\left({n} \frac{\pi}{3}\right) \sin\left({n} \frac{\pi}{4}\right) ...\sin\left({n} \frac{\pi}{n-1}\right) 
$$

And, is this the correct way to write it?
$$
 \prod_{m=2}^{n-1} \sin\left(n \frac{\pi}{m}\right)
$$

I'm not a professional so I'd appreciate a simple explanation.

Comment: $\displaystyle \prod_{i=2}^{n-1} \sin\left(n \frac{\pi}{i}\right)$ is as good a way to write it as any.  $\displaystyle \prod_{i=2}^{n-1} \sin\left( \frac{n \pi}{i}\right)$ or $\displaystyle \prod_{i=2}^{n-1} \sin\left( \frac{n}{i}\pi\right)$ are alternatives, and some people might prefer to use $m$ rather than $i$ if they want to avoid confusion with $\sqrt{-1}$

Comment: This is the correct compact notation (rather than a simplification) i.e. it is just a shorthand for this product and has no explanation as such

Comment: If $n$ is composite, the product can be simplified to $0$. If $n$ is prime, I don't think there's a general simplification.

Comment: @Paul thank you, but my primary concern is to simplify it, or, if I use the correct words, get the "closed-form"

Comment: @DanielFischer Actually it was the primes that got me here, I came to the conclusion that if the product is other than zero, then n is prime.

Comment: @Paul That is exactly what I have in mind. If the result is 0 then the number is not a prime.

Comment: That's correct, @xpy, as long as $n > 1$. For natural $n \geqslant 2$, the product is nonzero if and only if $n$ is prime.

Comment: That's a funny and probably useless primality test.

Comment: @vrugtehagel my first thought was even funnier $\sum_{m=2}^{n-1}\lfloor 1- \mid\sin\left(n\frac{\pi}{m} \right)\mid\rfloor$

Comment: @xpy did you ever make progress on this, I had the same question earlier today and found this

Comment: @cytinus No, Unfortunately not... I'm not a mathematician but I suspect there is not much to be done here. If you find something more, please share.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.  Using de Moivre's formula $e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$ your product is related to all the finite series:

$$ n\pi  \times \left( \pm \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{1}{3} \dots \pm \frac{1}{n-1} \right)  \mod 1$$

Your product is a weighted sum of $e^{[\dots]}$ for all series of this kind, behaving like the Boltzmann partition function.  In fact the numbers in question wrap around the number like $[0,1]$ in a somewhat random fashion.

---

It's unlikely there is any simplification unless we try to **estimate** this series.

$$ \sum e^{n \pi i \cdot \left(  \pm \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{1}{3} \dots \pm \frac{1}{n-1}  \right)}$$

That average is very likely to be close to $0$ since these numbers are equidistributed on the unit circle.

[image]

A histogram shows a little bit of variance, but basically the same idea:

[image]

It's very difficult to say how close to $0$ this result is.  However there may be classical results for estimating random-ish sums of this type.

Comment: Sorry, but as I said, I'm not an expert in mathematics so I don't get this completely... How did you get to de Moivre's formula?